# Windows + Powershell: How to change Processor Affinity for all java.exe instances?

Tags: windows, cpu, powershell, windows-server-2012

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187241/change-affinity-of-process-with-windows-script) question at StackOverflow, I'm able to change processor affinity if an executable is running only in 1 instance with this command:

```
PowerShell "$Process = Get-Process java; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=11"
```

If 2 or more instances are running, I cannot change, and this is the output

```
C:\PowerShell "$Process = Get-Process java; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=11"
The property 'ProcessorAffinity' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:30
+ $Process = Get-Process java; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=11
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Does anyone knows how to change Processor Affinity for all java.exe instances using Powershell?

Comment: what happens if you change your command to the following? `PowerShell "$Process = Get-Process java | % { $_.ProcessorAffinity=11 }"`

Comment: This is an elegant solution and should be posted as an answer. The variable can also be removed, `Get-Process java | % { $_.ProcessorAffinity=15 }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to loop over each object to set its `ProcessorAffinity`

`| % {}` in PowerShell means `ForEach-Object` and is basically the same as a `foreach()` statement in other languages

as root said, you can remove the variable so your code gets shorter.

from a cmd window:

```
PowerShell "get-process java | % { $_.ProcessorAffinity=11 }"
```

in a batch file (the batch file handles `%` like a variable, so you need to write it 2 times or switch to `foreach`) :

```
PowerShell "get-process java | %% { $_.ProcessorAffinity=11 }"
PowerShell "get-process java | foreach { $_.ProcessorAffinity=11 }"
```

directly in PowerShell:

```
get-process java | % { $_.ProcessorAffinity=11 }
```

Comment: Totally successful! Worked like a charm. And thank you for the explanation about | % {}, that's what I needed.

Comment: Just a correction: When calling from inside a batch file the percent sign must be doubled: `PowerShell "get-process java | %% { $_.ProcessorAffinity=11 }"`

Comment: @adamitj are you sure? that wouldn't make any sense at all, since you would double the `Foreach-Object`. If I run that with `%%` I get an error. with `%` it works.

Comment: Yes, for sure. A single percent sign inside a batch file is intended to reference an argument passed outside (calling from OS or from cmd.exe) as in %1, %2,  or referencing another environment variable like %tmp%, etc. If I want to print one percent sign with echo, for example, I need to `echo %%`

Comment: @adamitj you're right! the bat-file doesn'0t behave the same as the cmd window itself. I will update my answer